# É possível compilar para IOS usando Delphi XE7 no Windows?

Tags: delphi, ios, windows

Olá queria saber se dá para compilar para IOS usando delphi XE7 no Windows, Quando eu tento compilar ele tenta usar o "Create a Connection Profile".

É obrigatório ter um Mac para compilar para IOS? Como eu faço para compilar no Windows.

[image: Imagem Exemplo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com experiência com outras plataformas (`Xamarin`) posso afirmar que para compilar/debugar é necessário ter uma máquina MAC (e não é qualquer uma, tem que rodar a mais nova versão Yosemite).

Aqui estão algumas opções:

1. Comprar um MAC (preço absurdo);
2. Hackintosh (rodar MAC no PC)
3. Comprar um MAC Mini (antigo) e fazer uma gambiarra para rodar Yosemite (meu caso, paguei R$ 700) 
    [Tutorial: MAC MINI 2007 + YOSEMITE - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDcmr4Des6I&list=PL7NqYH-8oKFEeFIIKhIrqLOy0OdTR7N1r&index=2)
4. [MacinCloud.com](http://www.macincloud.com/) Serviço que aluga máquinas virtual MAC, tem configurações com foco no desenvolvedor como:

   - Xcode with Application Loader and iOS Simulator for Apple Developers
   - Xamarin Studio with Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Mac, Xamarin.Android
   - RAD PAServer XE8, XE7 upd1, XE7, XE6 upd1, (Delphi Platform Assistant Server)
   - Entre outras.

Comment: Gostei da ideia do MacMini, já havia pensado nisto. Diga-me se possivel, a saida de video é hdmi? O mouse é usb ou é um  "mac-mouse", a performance (apenas para desenvolvimento de aplicativos e não jogos) é aceitável? Obrigado

Comment: No meu caso é DVI, porém comprei um adaptador HDMI para ligar na TV. O teclado é MAC e o mouse `NORMAL` USB. A performance para desenvolvimento é tranquila. `OBS:` WIFI não pegou, estou utilizado rede cabeada, vi um adaptador no ML que parece ser compatível mais ainda não comprei.

Comment: 700 quê? Euros ou reais?

Comment: :) Comprei usado no ML, reais mesmo.

Comment: Com certeza parece uma solução muito superior ao hackintosh... eu ia fazer a mesma pergunta que o @ramaral, *se este valor já era com o do "cambio"*

Answer (score 2):

Na documentação tem os requisitos:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Installation_Notes_for_XE7#Requirements_for_Developing_iOS_Applications

```
Requirements for Developing iOS Applications

    PC running Windows connected to an Intel-based Mac, or a Mac running Windows in a VM, with 2 GB RAM or more.
    The Mac must run OS X 10.9 or 10.8, with the latest version of Xcode that supports iOS 7 or iOS 8.
    An Apple Developer account is required to deploy iOS apps to physical devices.
    Platform Assistant server (paserver) installed on the Mac:
```

Comment: Alexandre é uma boa resposta, porém considere edite-la adicionando ao inicio da resposta algo como: *É possível porém é necessário alguns requisitos, como descrito na documentação.*. É apenas uma sugestão.